# Matlab padarray function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of size `350X450`. I'm trying to pad with zeros the matrix which represents the image in a way that I'll have the original matrix in the center of the new padded matrix with a new dimensions of `700X900`. Here is what I want to do:

[image: Original image and desired image]

I'm trying to implement that using `padarray` function:

(Suppose **w** is the desired width, **h** is the desired height and **im** is the image(matrix))

```
new_image=paddarray(im, [0.5*w 0.5*h]);
```

I don't get the desired result. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm getting a `750X750` matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is right, you should set `w = ceil((700-350)/2)` and `h = ceil((900-450)/2)`.

Answer (score 1):

As the HELP entry says:

```
B = padarray(A,PADSIZE)
```

> pads array A with PADSIZE(k) number of zeros along the k-th dimension of A.

```
padarray([1 2; 3 4],[1 1]) %makes a 4x4 matrix
```

You don't want to pad with w and h, you want to pad with

`(wDesired - wCurrent)/2  %floor or ceil`, depending on your mood.